# Npm fetch freezes program when I execute response clone

Tags: fetch

I have a function :

```
public async execute(): Promise<Response> {
  const result = await fetch(this.url, this.params);
  const result2 = result.clone(); // if I have this, my console.log(await result.json().message) won't get executed, if I remove this line it will be executed.

  // if (result2.status !== 200) {
  //   logger.warn({
  //     msg: await result2.json(),
  //     function: `fetch-request result for ${this.url}, status: ${result.status}`,
  //   });
  // }

  return result;
}
```

And I use it:

```
public static async getSth() {
   return await request.execute(); // I ommit imports and stuff here does not matter
}

const result = await getSth();
console.log(await result.json().message);
```

My problem is I want to log things when request status !== 200, but I also want to log the message after I consumed the body. So I thought I will use clone() and consume another body of the clone, but when I try this, my second console log does not even gets executed. Why ?

Comment: npm fetch ? what do you mean by that and I tested your code in browser and indeed it works as expected (cloned res executes) so can you brief more.

Comment: I have a lambda where I use it. Somehow when clone is not used it all works fine, but as soon I add clone function it does not work, and not throwing any error even. Just the console.log from previous code example is not being logged.
```
export const myLambdaFunc(event, context) => {
  await Promise.all(
     event.records.map(async record) => {
       return await getSth();
    }

}

```

Comment: the code yous just sent its broken, try this and let me know does it works ```export const myLambdaFunc = (event, content) => Promise.all(event.records.map((record) => getSth()))```

Comment: @bogdanoff I narrowed the scenario (I removed promise.all for simplicty and processing just one item).

 When I add this line:
`const result2 = result.clone();` and do NOTHING with it after just unused variable, I get this:

**body used already for**,  So clone() consumes the body ? If I remove this line, evertyhing works ok. Is this node fetch bug ? (I use ^2.6.7)

From docs I assumed it should work with clone not throwing this error.

Comment: you should have mentioned that you are using 'node-fetch', any way I just installed same `node-fetch@2.6.7 ` but I dont see that error. here is code and try this on your machine. 
 ```import fetch from 'node-fetch'

const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
const r1 = response.clone()

console.log(await response.json())
console.log(await r1.text())````

Comment: on other hand you said "its hangs when I try to clone" right ? 
I think its because of [this](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#custom-highwatermark)